# Getting google calendar, "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, gmail, lumen

I want's to send invitation email's in **Lumen**.

Currently using: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar

This package is in **Lumen** (Laravel micro framework).

I have completed all the Google API related steps given in this package. But still getting Google exception as

> "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."

Even though I have enabled domain wide delegation in service account.

Also had doubt, Is it compulsory to have gsuite account? I am just trying with my normal gmail account.

Comment: i have the same problem.

Comment: are there some news?

Comment: Nope. I had managed by generating .ics file ..